# Hotkey for running command

Tags: sublimetext3

I want to create a keyboard shortcut in Sublime Text 3.

The command I want to run is something like this:

[make.sublime-build]

```
{
  "name": "boot-dev-svr",
  "cmd": ["java","-jar","D:\\prg\\boot\\boot-1.1.1.jar","development"],
  "working_dir": "D:/smx",
  "path": "C:/Windows/System32",
}
```

The key I want to map this action to is F5:

[Default (Windows).sublime-keymap - User]

```
[
    { "keys": ["f5"], "command": "BLAH BLAH BLAH" },
]
```

Seems like it should be simple, but "cmd" and "command" seem to be fundamentally different. I have not managed to get it to work.

How do I put these things together to do what I want in Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wound up doing, which seems to work, more or less.

Build:

```
{
  "cmd": ["python","prj.py","--runmake","serve"],
  "working_dir": "D:/smx",
  "path": "C:/Python27",

  "variants":
  [
    {
      "name": "boot-dev-svr",
      "cmd": ["java","-jar","D:\\prg\\boot\\boot-1.1.1.jar","development"],
      "working_dir": "D:/smx",
      "path": "C:/Windows/System32",
    },
  ]
}
```

Keymap:

```
[
  { "keys": ["f5"], "command": "build", "args": {"variant": "boot-dev-svr"} },
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried putting the actual command in **[]** 
That worked for me.

Another solution would be to update Sublime Text 3 to the latest release, sometimes that fixes the bug.

Hope I helped!

**EDIT**

Try removing the comma from the end of make.subime-build, like this

```
{
"name": "boot-dev-svr",
  "cmd": ["java","-jar","D:\\prg\\boot\\boot-1.1.1.jar","development"],
  "working_dir": "D:/smx",
  "path": "C:/Windows/System32",
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please paste it exactly?

Comment: In your **User (Windows).sublime-keymap** the command should be, in your case, `boot-dev-svr`

Comment: Hi, unless I did something wrong, I was not able to get this answer to work. However, it did mention that the "name" field is related to the keymap "command", so I marked it helpful.